# Horizontal List as a ControlSource for Excel-VBA form ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am looking to utilize a combo box on my excel-VBA form.

My source is a horizontal list (headings of some columns).

Any method I've found so far results in only the first item of my list being populated in the combo box control.

Is there something I need to do differently to make sure that:

```
combobox1.ControlSource
```

is accurately grabbing everything in the horizontal list and not just the first item?

Thanks for the help! 
-Kyle

Comment: Please show us your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best suggestion is to do a for loop

**CODE:**

```
for each cell in range("A1:G1") 'for example
    combobox1.additem(cell.value)
next cell
```

it is also a good idea to clear the comboboxes items before this to prevent duplicates the code for that is just `combobox1.clear()`

you could also use `xlright` for the loop but that isn't very reliable

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked great!! Thank you I hadn't thought of this. Still kind of new to VBA so thanks!